# Flying to Germany Alone, Return with Family

Tags: air-travel, germany, bookings, solo-travel, family

Alright so I am flying to Germany alone and want to return with my spouse and daughter. They will need a return ticket back, how exactly can I book this online?

Comment: you want to go to germany and come back with your family; and your family wants to exit germany to your current country and return to germany afterwards? right?

Comment: Yes correct. I have already booked my one way to Germany. I am bringing them here for a few months (USA). They are going back, so is there a way to delete myself on the return ticket?

Comment: Why did you book a one way to Germany? Shouldn't you have got a return ticket? Because you are coming back to USA with them.

Comment: Yes Newton is right. You should have booked yourself a to and fro ticket and then another to and fro ticket for your family with the corresponding dates. In your current situation, you can book yourself a separate one way ticket now.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you would plan your itinerary thus:

1. Book a return ticket for you, the origin is your current location.
2. Book a return ticket for your family, the origin is Germany and the destination is your current location.

Next, make sure your return flight (from Germany) is the same as their departing flight.

However, as you have already booked your one-way to Germany, you would need to now:

1. Book a return flight for your family; Germany - Your Location - Germany.
2. Book yourself a one way ticket on the same flight; Germany - Your Location.

Comment: This, in many cases one way tickets are also much more expensive so you want to try and get as many returns as you can.